# Rails NoMethodError (undefined method `something ' for Time:Class): not so trivial error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  # some code
  after_create :send_verification_email

  def send_verification_email
    puts 'edit 1', Time.now # it prints the actual date
    user_is_new = Time.now - user.created_at < 30 # This line pops an error
    unless verified || user_is_new # less than 30 seconds
      #some other code
```

I get an error at user_is_new=...

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `now ' for Time:Class):
```

WHY this error pops?

I have already test in rails console and works fine, but in a request crash

---

### Solution

Remove (replace) the (non-ascii?)space near the minus

```
user_is_new = Time.now-user.created_at < 30
```

Comment: Looks like a name clash. Did you happen to have a custom class named Time?

Comment: Nope I will edit for you

Comment: You sure you didn't cut and paste that in? Looks like a non-ascii-space whitespace. Retype the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `now ' for Time:Class):
```

It says `now`  not `now` or as in any other case, where the method can't be found. Try deleting the space right after the `now` method name.

Comment: WOW the spaces near the minus crash the process. Thanks mate!

Comment: I was facing the same problems everytime I opened curly braces. I turned on the invisibles characters in the editor to have an extra help.

Comment: This helped me as well, fwiw, in the browser error message the error looks like: `undefined method 'n­­o­w' for Time:Class` but in the terminal it shows `n  o w`